# IOTA Whitepaper: What is δ?

Tags: iota-network, white-paper

In Section 3.1 of the IOTA Whitepaper it refers to small delta (δ) but does not actually define what it does.  Can you help define δ and explain what the equation is trying to tell me?

[image: δ]

Comment: A general technique when proving or deducing limits or differentials is to derive what happens if you add a small value (delta > 0, often you also use epsilon if not used in the proof so far) to a large one (t). That is also where the maths joke "let epsilon be less than zero" comes from. I don't know what the exact part of the whitepaper tries to prove since usually when some limits or derivatives are involved I first try to skip over it and try if I can understand the rest without it.

Comment: @mihi I agree delta is small, but I think *t* doesn't have to be big necessarily. Similar to when you look at f'(t) ≈ ( f(t+delta) - f(t) ) / delta, where *t* just has to be in the domain of f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H(t) represent the expected cumulative weight at time t.

∂ is a way to note a very small *delta* time.

The first equation explicit the value the H function relatively to the value of the H function a very small time before.

The second equation is the differential of the first one. In other words, *dH(t)/dt* is the slope of the function H(t)